# A lot of sleeping processes and Aborted_client - Does it related to mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I use this "get_mysql_query" function for all of my queries, this help me to keep the code clean.

I'm not sure when and if the connection with the database is close.

Does the connection close in the end of the function, and $WebResult is Independent variable.

I'm asking this because I have a lot of sleeping processes and Aborted_clients, And I thought it may be a time connection between the query and its closure.

```
function open_mysql_connection(){
    global $openconn,$conn;
    $servername = "p:1.1.1.1"; 
    $username = "demo";
    $password = "demo";

    $dbname = "demo";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    /* change character set to utf8 */
    $conn->set_charset("utf8");
    $openconn = true;
}  

function close_mysql_connection(){
    global $openconn,$conn;
    if ($openconn){
        $conn->close();
        $openconn = false;  
    }   
}   

function get_mysql_query($query,$prepare=NULL,$prepare_type=NULL){
    global $openconn,$conn,$memcache,$LASTID;

    if (!$openconn){
        open_mysql_connection();
    }
    if ($prepare!=NULL){
        $sql =$query;
        $a_bind_params   =$prepare;
        $a_param_type =$prepare_type;

        /* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
        $a_params = array();

        $param_type = '';
        $n = count($a_param_type);
        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          $param_type .= $a_param_type[$i];
        }

        /* with call_user_func_array, array params must be passed by reference */
        $a_params[] = & $param_type;

        for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
          /* with call_user_func_array, array params must be passed by reference */
          $a_params[] = & $a_bind_params[$i];
        }

        /* Prepare statement */
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        if($stmt === false) {
          trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        /* use call_user_func_array, as $stmt->bind_param('s', $param); does not accept params array */
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $a_params);

        /* Execute statement */
        $stmt->execute();

        // /* Store the result (to get properties) */
        // $stmt->store_result();

        /* Fetch result to array */ 
        $result = $stmt->get_result(); // altenative: $stmt->bind_result($row_AcousticDB);

        $LASTID =  $stmt->insert_id;    
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
        close_mysql_connection();
        return $result;
    }else{      
        $result =$conn->query($query,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);  
        $LASTID =  $conn->insert_id;    
        close_mysql_connection();
        return $result;
    }
};


    $query_terms[]=$_GET["p"];
    $prepare_type[]='i';    
    $query =" SELECT * from   `tbl_post` where id = ?  ";
    $WebResult = get_mysql_query($query,$query_terms,$prepare_type);            
        if ($WebResult->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $WebResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $row['ID'];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you close the connection after each and every query?

Answer (score -2):

//try removing this 
close_mysql_connection();

Comment: any reason for that?